# In the context of emails, what can be digitally signed and what should be digitally signed in the sub context of deal documents?

Tags: email, account-security, money

I was once a customer of a certain developer who sold a *SaaS* bookkeeping software which allowed sending deal documents (invoice, receipt, etc) to a customer, from the software's very own email server, and any **content** sent was always digitally signed.

I know that in the context of emails, at least four "aspects" can be digitally signed:

- The email server itself
- The timestamp of sending
- The sending source (email address I would presume)
- The **content** of an email sent (including attached files)

### My questions

1. In the context of emails, what **can** be digitally signed (did I describe the aspects accurately and/or missed a certain aspect)?
2. What **should** be digitally signed in the sub context of deal documents (I know that some bookkeeping software don't allow digitally signing anything and I want to know why some do and some don't)

Comment: #1 is answerable but #2 isn't - it just depends. A B2C e-commerce system won't bother signing anything because no one will bother checking it and won't care. Actually, that holds true for most B2B transactions to. In fact I can't think of why most would care about this, although I'm sure there are some cases when it would help